# Converting a string into a list and removing prefixes and suffixes

Tags: python, string, list

I want to convert a string of the form:

> {{0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
>     1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
>     0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
>     0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}}

into a list that looks exactly like it (that is I have a string written as if it were a list, except I would need to replace each { with a [ and each } with a ] in order to work with it as a list in python. Any ideas?

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: @avasal: The string I am referring to is an input string from Mathematica

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
eval(s.replace("{", "[").replace("}", "]"))
```

Comment: Use @Paul McQuire's suggestion of literal_eval. It'll be both faster and safer.

Answer (score 3):

You will need two functions from the standard lib:

- str.replace
- ast.literal_eval